# Differences between user mode and system mode in ARM

Tags: arm, embedded

The following excerpt comes from [ARM system developer's guide](http://mazsola.iit.uni-miskolc.hu/~drdani/docs_arm/36_Elsevier-ARM_Sy.pdf)
[image: Complete ARM register set]

> Every processor mode except user mode can change mode by writing
>   directly to the mode bits of the cpsr. All processor modes except
>   system mode have a set of associated banked registers that are a
>   subset of the main 16 registers.

My question are:

1. Is User mode and System mode the same? Or different mode?
2. Can System mode change mode by writing directly to the mode bits of the cpsr?
3. Does User mode have a set of associated banked registers that are a subset of the main 16 registers?

Comment: the picture answers your third question, system and user share the same registers.   If you read the archtiectural reference manual you will see what things user can and cant do (as well as system).  user and system mode are not the same otherwise they wouldnt list them as two things.   they have different permissions beyond just access to the general purpose registers.

Comment: read the architectural reference manual I recommend you start with the older one the armv5 architectural reference manual from infocenter.arm.com  these other documents are interesting but even others from arm are misleading and confusing.

Comment: @old_timer I think that in addition to system mode, user mode does not have a set of associated banked registers that are a subset of the main 16 registers.

Comment: as shown in the image, system and user use the same bank of registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is User mode and System mode the same? Or different mode?

From the same reference you linked, section *2.2.1 Processor Modes*

> *System mode is a special version of user mode that allows full
>   read-write access to the cpsr*

---

> 2. Can System mode change mode by writing directly to the mode bits of the cpsr?

See above.

---

> 3. Does User mode have a set of associated banked registers that are a subset of the main 16 registers?

It uses the same registers as System mode; it is only the CPSR access that differs.

Comment: Per your answer in Q3. I believe this book is offering wrong info. It should say "All processor modes except system mode **and user mode** have a set of associated banked registers that are a subset of the main 16 registers."

Comment: @AndyLin : that is a semantic issue.  The text is correct, but possibly unclear.  It is your interpretation of it that is incorrect. The normal register bank is the user mode bank, the system mode does not switch to an alternate bank, so in that sense does not have its own registers.  The diagram offers clarity perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is User mode and System mode the same? Or different mode?

Also, from the same reference you linked, section 2.1 *REGISTERS*

> The processor can operate in seven different modes, which we will
>   introduce shortly.

You can infer that System mode and User mode are the different mode.

> 2. Can System mode change mode by writing directly to the mode bits of the cpsr?

Since System mode and User mode are the different mode, System mode definitely can change mode by writing directly to the mode bits of the cpsr. According to your reference below the image.

> 3. Does User mode have a set of associated banked registers that are a subset of the main 16 registers?

No, it does not.

I insist that this is manual's typo.